# How can I change the colour of the column header in geom_table() in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

I'm using the `geom_table()` function from the `ggpmisc` package to add a table legend to my figure. I want to remove the grey colour from the first row with the column headers.

```
library(ggpmisc)
library(tidyverse)

mtcars %>%
  group_by(cyl) %>%
  summarize(wt = mean(wt), mpg = mean(mpg)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  mutate(wt = sprintf("%.2f", wt),
         mpg = sprintf("%.1f", mpg)) -> tb

df <- tibble(x = 5.45, y = 34, tb = list(tb))

ggplot(mtcars, aes(wt, mpg, colour = factor(cyl))) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_table(data = df, aes(x = x, y = y, label = tb),
             table.theme = ttheme_gtbw)
```

[image]

Comment: Have you look at here?: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggpmisc/vignettes/user-guide.html#geom_table-and-stat_fmt_table

Comment: I did indeed, there isn't an example there that shows how to control that colour unfortunately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the theme using arguments that are passed from `ggpmisc` to the corresponding `ttheme` function from `gridExtra` ([Description](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gridExtra/vignettes/tableGrob.html#aesthetic-formatting) of some of the possible options). If I understand your question correctly you want the background of the first row in your table to be white. You can achieve this using the following code to build your plot:

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(wt, mpg, colour = factor(cyl))) +
    geom_point() +
    geom_table(data = df, aes(x = x, y = y, label = tb),
               table.theme = ttheme_gtbw(colhead = list(bg_params = list(fill = "white"))))
```

[image: Result with white first row in table]